# Comment author. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want show the user email as author of comment, but I see this error "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"
**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
  has_many :comments
end
```

**hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :address
  has_many :comments
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment = @hotel.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @hotel
  end

private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :hotel_id)
  end
```

**_comments.html.haml**

```
= div_for comment do
  %p
    %strong
      Posted #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago
    %br/
    = h comment.user.email
    %br
    = comment.body
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method**

The error that you're calling a method which doesn't exist.

The problem is you're calling a method on an associated object which doesn't exist. You probably don't have any `user` associated to the `comment` - thus preventing you from being able to call the `email` method.

Firstly, you need to make sure you have the correct association. Here's how to do that:

```
$ rails c
$ comment = Comment.find([id])
$ comment.update(user_id: [your_user_id])
$ exit
```

This will allow you to associate the comment to a particular user, giving you the ability to call the associated method.

--

**Controller**

When you save your `comment` in your controller, you need to assign your `user` to it. We do this using the `strong_params` functionality, as its the DRYest way we've found:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
       @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    end

    private
    def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:your, :comment: attributes).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

This will allow you to associate the user at save time, giving you the ability to call the methods you need next time you call the record!

---

**Delegate**

You'll also benefit from using the [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method like this:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :hotel

   delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true #-> allows you to call `@comment.user_email`
end
```

This will solve the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) issue (where you should aim to have one "point" in your calls")

Comment: No problem! Would you like me to detail how a controller would work for that?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice:)